# IndexedDB creating an index with a space

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am trying to create an index with the following line

```
objectStore.createIndex('Team Name', 'Team Name', { unique: false });
```

this will return the following error
Uncaught Error: SyntaxError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 12

However if I create the index and remove the space like this

```
objectStore.createIndex('Team Name', 'TeamName', { unique: false });
```

It works. This means I need to modify the data returned from an ajax call to work with the fix. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter to `.createIndex()` is a key path and:

> NOTE: Spaces are not allowed within a keypath.

Reference: [W3C IndexedDB Specification Key Path](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dfn-key-path)

Comment: Thanks. I think I am still a little confused on how these keys are setup. My data is example { field1: 'a', field2: 'b', 'team name': 'c' } how would i make 'team name' an index?

Comment: You can remove any spaces in your keys using regular expressions: `'team name'.replace(/\s+/, "")`